# Android application is not installed on Nokia XL

Tags: android

I develop an android application and suppose to run any android version.
I notice that I can only install my application on android which has Google Play install. I think this is because I use Google Play library. Is there any way to install my application on android which has no Google Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

if you dont absolutely need google play services, use other library.

or you can detect if a device doesnt have it, then display some information about installing the google play services on that device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can i detect if I cannot install this app?. of course, i can detect if there is google_play_service when application started.

Comment: so you failed to install at all? im sorry i misread, you cannot detect that. however if you have the device you can connect it to your computer which enables you to get the error message. perhaps you want to look again at your manifest? especially on minimumSdkVersion part